# Regarding strings in printf

Tags: c, printf, file-handling

From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059317/5859944

```
FILE *fileptr;
char *buffer;
long filelen;

fileptr = fopen("myfile.txt", "rb");  // Open the file in binary mode
fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);          // Jump to the end of the file
filelen = ftell(fileptr);             // Get the current byte offset 
                                         in the file
rewind(fileptr);                      // Jump back to the beginning of 
                                         the file

buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); // Enough memory 
                                                      for file + \0
fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr); // Read in the entire file
fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
```

You read a file as a byte array.

As it is clear that it is nothing but a string.
One could add a

```
buffer[filelen] = '\0';
```

and

```
printf("%s" , buffer);
```

should print the entrire contents of a file as if it were a string. And it  does so in simple text files but not in binary ones.

For binary files , one has to write a function as follows:

```
void traverse(char *string ,size_t size){
  for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%c",string[i]);
}
```

and print each character one by one.
Which puts gibberish on the screen.

- Why `printf` doesn't treat `buffer` as a character string incase of binary files?
- Why `printf` in function `traverse` puts gibberish instead of characters?

For the second bullet point, I know that it maybe due to `signed char` but even if the string is stored as `unsigned char` results are still the same.

Comment: Binary files are often containing zeros. That is the `\0` characters.

Comment: reading a text file _as binary_ will make your functions print properly

Comment: A character string is null terminated. If there is a 0 byte in the string then as far as printf is concerned that is the end of the string. Not all characters are printable, so if your file contains those then you get gibberish.

Comment: And yes, "gibberish" *is* characters.

Comment: Let's define what *text file* is :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would that "gibberish" be not treated as `unsigned char` when the byte array is `unsigned char`?

Comment: When you print it as `%c` it really doesn't matter signed or unsigned. It is character. Characters (in common meaning) don't have signs.

Comment: When `"%c"` is used, the `int` argument is converted to `unsigned char` during `printf()` processing and the corresponding character is printed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Any suggestions on achieving that?

Comment: What is "that"?

Comment: gibberish to `unsigned char` when printing.

Comment: You want to print numeric values? Then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736497/how-to-print-an-unsigned-char-in-c Looks like your question is totally unrelated to your real problem then.

Comment: Try `printf("%c",string[i]);` --> `printf(" %hhu",string[i]);`

Comment: BTW, that `fread` line and its comment 'Read in the entire file' are wrong. It is possible that `fread` returns less than you asked for. Which is why it has a return value. That return value **MUST BE CHECKED**. Otherwise, so many bugs.

Comment: "As it is clear that it is nothing but a string". It is not. The file is binary. Binary files are not strings. "Which puts gibberish on the screen" What do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why printf doesn't treat buffer as a character string incase of binary files?

`printf("%s",buffer)` *does* assume that `buffer` contains a C string.  The problem is, that's not what `buffer` actually contains.  Your `buffer` actually contains the bytes from a binary file.

A C string is terminated by the first zero byte (a.k.a., '\0', a.k.a., ASCII NUL), and an arbitrary non-text file (a.k.a., "binary file") could contain zero bytes anywhere within itself.  The printf "%s" format will stop as soon as it sees the first zero byte.

> Why printf in function traverse puts gibberish instead of characters?

That "gibberish" *is* characters.  But the characters don't mean anything because the file that you are trying to interpret as a sequence of characters was not meant to be interpreted in that way.

A text file is a sequence of bytes that are meant to be rendered according to some *[character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)*, and which *usually* is meant to convey some kind of human-readable information.  An arbitrary "binary" file probably contains a sequence of bytes that are not supposed to represent human readable text.  They represent something else, that some computer program understands.

The printf `"%s"` *attempts* to render those bytes according to some character encoding system (often either [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)), but (a) it won't always be able to do so, and (b) even when it *is* able to do so, the character sequence won't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem here is you are mixing the purposing of how your reading the file. To read *binary* data from a file, and subsequently print that binary data, you should always use `unsigned char` and `unsigned char*` to store data read from a *binary* file.

This is because in order to get an accurate representation of that data printed, you need to use the `"%u"` type flag in format strings to `printf`. Only [some characters are printable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) according to ASCII, meaning if you desire to see all the binary data in your file, you will not be able to see some of it printed if you use the `"%c"` flag.

A binary version of your function would be:

```
void traverse(unsigned char *string ,size_t size){
  for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%u",string[i]);
}
```

The second issue is

> should print the entrire contents of a file as if it were a string. And it does so in simple text files but not in binary ones.

This is not true. Using the `"%s"` flag prints characters as if they were printable chars, it will terminate when it reaches a null, `\0` character. You cannot efficiently use `%s` to print binary data.